Error on 2/3 applications: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
I am deploying 3 applications on a windows server: back and front end projects and one fullstack project. Catalina.log shows that it deploys successfully, but only the back end project is working, so both of the front end project and the fullstack project get this error. They are running on Tomcat 9.
2024-12-17 11:01:14,461 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application archive [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\ConBaseServer##0000000003341271.war]
2024-12-17 11:01:18,398 [main] INFO  org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner- At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-12-17 11:01:18,445 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[10.11.24.37].[/ConBaseServer##0000000003341271]- No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2024-12-17 11:01:19,117 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deployment of web application archive [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\ConBaseServer##0000000003341271.war] has finished in [4,640] ms
2024-12-17 11:01:19,117 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application archive [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\ETOVDashboard##0000000003611696.war]
2024-12-17 11:01:19,570 [main] INFO  org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner- At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-12-17 11:01:19,570 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deployment of web application archive [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\ETOVDashboard##0000000003611696.war] has finished in [453] ms
2024-12-17 11:01:19,976 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application archive [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\npi-dashboard-backend##0000000003341296.war]
2024-12-17 11:01:23,898 [main] INFO  org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner- At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-12-17 11:01:23,914 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[10.11.24.37].[/npi-dashboard-backend##0000000003341296]- 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2024-12-17 11:01:29,023 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[10.11.24.37].[/npi-dashboard-backend##0000000003341296]- Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-12-17 11:01:34,992 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deployment of web application archive [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\npi-dashboard-backend##0000000003341296.war] has finished in [15,016] ms
2024-12-17 11:01:34,992 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application archive [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\npi-dashboard-backend.war]
2024-12-17 11:01:38,539 [main] INFO  org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner- At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-12-17 11:01:38,555 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[10.11.24.37].[/npi-dashboard-backend]- 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2024-12-17 11:01:43,367 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[10.11.24.37].[/npi-dashboard-backend]- Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-12-17 11:01:48,747 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deployment of web application archive [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\npi-dashboard-backend.war] has finished in [13,755] ms
2024-12-17 11:01:48,747 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application directory [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\errorpages]
2024-12-17 11:01:49,080 [main] INFO  org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner- At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-12-17 11:01:49,080 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deployment of web application directory [D:\Program Files\Tomcat-Instances\ConBase-P1\webapps\errorpages] has finished in [333] ms
2024-12-17 11:01:49,080 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol- Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
2024-12-17 11:01:49,095 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Server startup in [34777] milliseconds
2024-12-17 11:12:50,574 [http-nio-80-exec-13] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[10.11.24.37].[/npi-dashboard-backend##0000000003341296]- Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

The interesting part, is the same war files work on another server with the same tomcat config. The only difference is the the database connection, which is working fine.
